# Instantly update a textbox in InfoPath 2007

Tags: textbox, infopath-2007

I'm trying to create an input form similar to a text message. I have a large textbox for the message, and I have a small textbox that is read-only that I want to show the character count.

I got this to work by setting the default value of the small textbook to the string length of the large textbox. This works correctly, but I would like to update the small textbox every time a character is entered into the large textbox, not every time I click off of the large textbox.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: It's been several months, so since I found an answer to this question, I'll post it to help anyone else looking for the same thing.*

This is not possible using the default controls and properties in InfoPath 2007. In general, InfoPath can only respond to events when a field's value is finished being modified.  It may be possible to do this with a custom ActiveX control.